# Update vertices geometry Threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

I made a function to get the geometry's vertices position but if I drag the geometry in other part of screen it shows me always the old coordinates.

```
 for(var j=0 ; j<geometryContainer.length ; j++) {     

  for (var i=0 ; i<geometryContainer[j].geometry.vertices.length ; i++){
  geometryContainer[j].geometry.verticesNeedUpdate=true;
  x=geometryContainer[j].geometry.vertices[i].x;
  y=geometryContainer[j].geometry.vertices[i].y;
  z=geometryContainer[j].geometry.vertices[i].z;

  console.log(x + ',' + y + ',' + z);
   } 
 }
```

Comment: My question is, why do you want to change the vertices? You nearly always want to move its container around instead of actually modifying the vertices.

Answer (score 1):

The vertices's position are relative to the object itself.If you want to get the vertices's position relative to the coordinate,get the geometry's position and add the offset of the vertex.